# Convert VBA code in MS Access to SQL server

Tags: sql-server, ms-access

The following code is from MS Access, and I am trying to convert it nad make it works in SQL server. I dont know how to convert the last line, which contains IsNull. 
P.S:LIS is a name of drive. 
Thanks for anyone who can give me hints.

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Molecular Pathology].[ID#], [Molecular Pathology].[Last Name], 
[Molecular Pathology].[First Name], [Molecular Pathology].Gender, 
[Molecular Pathology].[Date of Birth], [Molecular Tests].[Test Type], 
[Molecular Pathology].[Testing Gene], [Molecular Pathology].[Testing Exon], 
[Molecular Pathology].[Tested Mutation], [Molecular Pathology].[Testing Gene 2], 
[Molecular Pathology].[Testing Exon 2], [Molecular Pathology].[Tested Mutation 2], 
[Molecular Tests].[Test Name], [Molecular Pathology].[Result Reported],
[Molecular Pathology].[Date Received], [Molecular Pathology].[gp#]
FROM ([Molecular Pathology] 
LEFT JOIN [Molecular Select Tests] 
  ON [Molecular Pathology].ID = [Molecular Select Tests].ForKey) 
LEFT JOIN [Molecular Tests] 
  ON [Molecular Select Tests].Test = [Molecular Tests].[Test Name]
WHERE ((IsNull([Molecular Pathology].[LIS SignOut])<>False));
```

Answer (score 1):

Only a couple of minor issues, however you could improve this query's readability greatly by making proper use of table aliases. Please try this re-write:

```
SELECT DISTINCT 
  mp.[ID#],            mp.[Last Name],       mp.[First Name], 
  mp.Gender,           mp.[Date of Birth],   mt.[Test Type],       
  mp.[Testing Gene],   mp.[Testing Exon],    mp.[Tested Mutation], 
  mp.[Testing Gene 2], mp.[Testing Exon 2],  mp.[Tested Mutation 2], 
  mt.[Test Name],      mp.[Result Reported], mp.[Date Received],
  mp.[gp#]
FROM 
  dbo.[Molecular Pathology] AS mp 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  dbo.[Molecular Select Tests] AS mst
  ON mp.ID = mst.ForKey -- Molecular Pathology has an ID column and an ID# column? 
LEFT OUTER JOIN 
  dbo.[Molecular Tests] AS mt
  ON mst.Test = mt.[Test Name]
WHERE 
  mp.[LIS SignOut] IS NULL;
```

Comment: did you manually line up the fields into 3 columns, or do you have a program that does it for you. And if you do have a program, can I get the name of it please? Thanks.

Comment: @TomCollins sorry to disappoint but that was just manual spacebar bludgeoning.

Comment: oh well. Here's one I use quite a bit, especially when coding as it will build my code strings for me. 
[link](http://www.dpriver.com/pp/sqlformat.htm)

Comment: @AaronBertrand Thank you so much for your help in both questions. I really appreciate that!!Thanks.

Comment: @AaronBertrand Do you know where can I get a guidebook about MS Access and SQL server script conversion? I really need to learn the converting between code in work. Thank you in advance.

Comment: @MaggieMi there is a whitepaper here (SSMAAccess.docx) that seems to detail all of the potential syntax issues. http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=8775